# Only show rows where certain data does not match

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains if an employee has logged into work or not.  A new row is inserted when they log in and when they log out.  What I am wanting to do is result on the employees that have not logged out on todays date.

The table structure is as below:

| Employee_Ref | ShiftDate | In_or_Out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 191 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00.000 | I |
| 320 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00.000 | I |
| 320 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00.000 | O |

Result required would be:

| Employee_Ref | ShiftDate | In_or_Out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 191 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00.000 | I |

Could anyone help please?

Comment: What implementation of SQL is this in? Have you tried any queries and had any specific problems?

Comment: Are you stuck on the usage of `I` and `O`? Why not replace it with `+1` and `-1`? Then you could SUM the In_Or_Out column and `GROUP BY` Employee_Ref, ShiftDate, and use a `HAVING` clause of SUM() <> 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am wanting to do is result on the employees that have not logged out on todays date.

Presumably, you want people who did log in on today's date.  I'll assume that is the case.

You can use aggregation if you want *employees*:

```
select employee_ref
from t
where shiftdate >= current_date and
      shiftdate < current_date + interval '1 day'
group by employee_ref
having sum(case when in_or_out = 'O' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

You can use `not exists` if you want the detailed rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where shiftdate >= current_date and
      shiftdate < current_date + interval '1 day' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.employee_ref = t.employee_ref and
                        t2.shiftdate >= current_date and
                        t2.shiftdate < current_date + interval '1 day' and
                        t2.in_or_out = 'O'
                 );
```

Note that date functions vary significantly among databases.  This uses standard SQL syntax that can be adapted to your database.

Comment: Hi thanks, this works to an extent but employees can log in and out several times during the day

Comment: @BobJones . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: Sorted it thanks

'select Employee_Ref
from CLOCKING
where Shift_Date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) and
      Shift_Date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) +1 

group by Employee_Ref
having sum(case when In_or_Out = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) > sum(case when In_or_Out = 'O' then 1 else 0 end);'